# Single Quote in URL Gives Me Error on my new server, not on old (php)

Tags: php, apache

I shifted my hosting from Hostgator Shared to FDC Dedicated recently.
But since then I'm facing many problems in my php autoindex script. I managed to solve most of them, still a few are eating my head.

One of them is this:

Old Shared Hosting:
http://old.mp4.desiden.mobi/file.php?p=1&file=load/English%20Song%20Videos/Top%20Songs/Pitbull%20FtLil%27%20Jon%20-%20Krazy%28DesiDen.Mobi%29.mp4&sort=0

Current FDC Server:
http://desiden.mobi/Mp4_Song_Videos/file.php?p=1&file=load/English%20Song%20Videos/Top%20Songs/Pitbull%20FtLil%27%20Jon%20-%20Krazy%28DesiDen.Mobi%29.mp4&sort=1

The second one shows error for the same file and same script. This happens only if filename has single quote.

My script shows that error when a file is not found. So what I guess is, the script cannot find the file.

### Any idea ?

Comment: Add more information, what is the problem, how is your system working, which part of your code does not seems to be working ? what is the flow of data inside your code ?

Comment: I would surmise you didn't bother with SQL escaping. Old server had a dated magic_quotes setting, the new hasn't. And I also guess you'd go for just that lazy option, so no need to elaborate too much. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Or it could equally be the other way around, magic_quotes on the FDC server needing to be turned off.

Comment: My script does not use SQL. I have tried turning magic_quptes_gpc to OFF. Still not working. How do I check the flow of data ? My script shows that error when a file is not found. So what I guess is, the script cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the comments above, there must be a mismatch on server settings with magic_quotes. You'll need to change the code on the new server to use either of the following:

```
$var = stripslashes($var);
$var = addslashes($var);
```

I can't tell you which as we don't know the setup of the servers. Also, of course, make sure you use use your own variable name.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not get you. Could you explain ? Which variable should I edit ? I have turned magic_quotes_gpc OFF.

Comment: It seems to work now. I don't know why! I did not change anything! I just turned magic quotes ON and then back to OFF.